# Upgrade psql on Mac OS - Mismatching client and server versions. Some psql features might not work

Tags: postgresql, macos, terminal, homebrew, psql

I have just upgraded to PostgreSQL 10.11 on macOS using Homebrew and I am now getting the following message:

```
psql crmpicco
psql (9.6.16, server 10.11)
WARNING: psql major version 9.6, server major version 10.
         Some psql features might not work.
Type "help" for help.

crmpicco=#
```

There's plenty of advice online for resolving this for Debian and Ubuntu, but nothing for MacOS/Homebrew.

How can I update `psql` locally to get rid of this message?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you didn't run upgrade command for brew `Postgres` after upgrade to new version:

```
brew postgresql-upgrade-database
```

incase it didn't work, there is a gist online for home-brew Postgres upgrade, its for old version but still valid in how to upgrade in mac:

[migrate_postgresql_database](https://gist.github.com/olivierlacan/e1bf5c34bc9f82e06bc0)

Comment: Hmmm, when I run that I get `Error: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /usr/local/var/postgres/PG_VERSION`

Comment: this is weird, try this `brew unlink postgresql && brew link postgresql` and then run the command.

Comment: I installed a specific version (10) so inside `/usr/local/Cellar` I have `postgresql@10` and `postgresql@9.6` :-/ 

`brew unlink postgresql@10
Unlinking /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@10/10.11... 0 symlinks removed`

`brew link postgresql@10 
Warning: postgresql@10 is keg-only and must be linked with --force`